# ASP.NET Core 3 Razor Page DataAnnotation Compare attribute returns "Could not find a property named <n>"

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a ASP.Net Core 3 razor page, a very simple reset password form, which uses a Compare Data Annotation to validate both inputs are the same, however, it doesn't seem to be working. The Required annotation triggers ok, but the Compare always returns ModelState.Valid == false and "Could not find a property named Password." as the error message.

the model is

```cs
        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
        [Compare(nameof(Password), ErrorMessage = "Passwords don't match")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

and the cshtml is

```html
    <form method="Post">
        <label>New Password</label>
        <input asp-for="Password" type="Password" >
        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>

        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" type="Password" >
        <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>

        <button type="Submit">Reset Password</button>
    </form>
```

I've paired back the code to the complete minimum and just can't seem to see what the issue is...

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4895

Comment: good grief - it's been an issue since june 2018!

Answer (score 3):

thanks to Kirk Larkin for pointing me to the github issue detailing this. I decided to create a nested viewmodel class to contain the properties. The Compare annotation now works correctly.

nested class looks like this...

```cs
        [BindProperty]
        public ViewModel viewModel { get; set; }
        public class ViewModel {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirmation Password is required.")]
            [Compare(nameof(Password), ErrorMessage = "Passwords don't match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }
```

and the web page now looks like this...

```html
    <form method="Post">
        <label>New Password</label>
        <input asp-for="viewModel.Password" type="Password" >
        <span asp-validation-for="viewModel.Password" class="text-danger"></span>

        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input asp-for="viewModel.ConfirmPassword" type="Password" >
        <span asp-validation-for="viewModel.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>

        <button type="Submit">Reset Password</button>
    </form>
```